# How to group an array of objects by another object inside in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a function that groups me the elements of the arrangement for a certain area, this would be the original array.

Some details:

There are elements of the array that have no zone.

If it does not have an equal zone, it is included.

The zone can not be repeated, that is to say if the element has no zone to include the element and if it has zone to include while the zone does not repeat.

this is a sample of the array:

There are elements without an area like this:

```
{_id: "455", name: "ALBACETE"}
```

And there are elements with zone:

```
{zone: {_id: "zone1", name: "zone1"}, _id: "143", name: "ALCALA"}
{zone: {_id: "zone1", name: "zone1"}, _id: "144", name: "OTRO"}
{zone: {_id: "zone2", name: "zone2"}, _id: "144", name: "OTRO MAS"}
```

For this example, what is needed is this result:

```
{_id: "455", name: "ALBACETE"}
{zone: {_id: "zone1", name: "zone1"}, _id: "143", name: "ALCALA"}
{zone: {_id: "zone2", name: "zone2"}, _id: "144", name: "OTRO MAS"}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: looks like you just need a `.filter`. well what have you tried? where do you stuck ?

Comment: Try filtering but I think I need to group but honestly I can not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should help not the cleanest code but ...

```
 const q = [
     { zone: { _id: "zone1", name: "zone1" }, _id: "143", name: "ALCALA" },
     { zone: { _id: "zone1", name: "zone1" }, _id: "144", name: "OTRO" },
     { zone: { _id: "zone2", name: "zone2" }, _id: "144", name: "OTRO MAS" },
     { _id: "455", name: "ALBACETE" }
 ];``


let ret = [];

let result = q.filter( x => {
  if(!ret.includes(x._id)) {
    ret.push(x._id);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log (result);
```

the output will be

```
[ 
   { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id: '143', name: 'ALCALA' },
   { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id: '144', name: 'OTRO' },
   { _id: '455', name: 'ALBACETE' } 
]
```

as you requested.

Comment: the output should be: zone 1 and zone 2. that is, eliminate the repeated registor zone 1, that way it would be grouped by _ID and by NAME.

Comment: Please any help?